# Teradata: I need to check the count of rows in a table and if the count is more than 1, i need to run an update query

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I need to check the count of rows in a table and if the count is more than 1, i need to run an update query. Is there any way i can do it without using a bteq script in teradata sql assistant?
The sequence should be something like below

1. Select count(*) from dbname.tablename;
2. if count(*)>0, then run update statement on dbname.tablename;

Comment: `update ..... where exists (select * from tab)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE dbname.tablename
SET <column>=<value> 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbname.tablename) >0;
```

Thanks